# Iterating through 2 lists at a time using while

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, while-loop

```
var itemAmountList = _itemAmountvalue.Split(',');
var listItemDescriptionValues = _itemDescriptionvalue.Split(',');

IEnumerator enum1 = itemAmountList.GetEnumerator();
IEnumerator enum2 = listItemDescriptionValues.GetEnumerator();

DataTable dtCustomInvoiceDetail = new DataTable();
dtCustomInvoiceDetail.Columns.Add("purchaseOrderID");
dtCustomInvoiceDetail.Columns.Add("itemAmount");
dtCustomInvoiceDetail.Columns.Add("itemDescription");

while ((enum1.MoveNext()) && (enum2.MoveNext()))
{
            var description = enum1.Current;
            var amount = enum2.Current;

            DataRow dr = dtCustomInvoiceDetail.NewRow();
            dr["itemDescription"] = description;
            dr["itemAmount"] = amount;
            dr["purchaseOrderID"] = strPoid;
}
```

Above is the code that I am using to iterate through a list and populate a datatable.

I do not see any rows added to the datatable

1. Verified the data and looks good
2. it iterates through the loop the no of times as required

But still do not see any data in the datatable

Comment: You are not adding `DataRow` to `DataTable` inside `While` loop. Add this to the end of the loop: 
`dtCustomInvoiceDetail.Rows.Add(dr )`

Comment: Thank You Farhad Jabiyev

Answer (score 3):

In your code

```
DataRow dr = dtCustomInvoiceDetail.NewRow();
```

does not actually add a row to the table, it only creates a table row with the correct columns. In order to add the row you need to call

```
dtCustomInvoiceDetail.Rows.Add(dr)
```

at the end

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are not adding the generated row to datatable.

[Datatable.NewRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> You must use the `NewRow` method to create new `DataRow` objects with
>   the same schema as the `DataTable`. After creating a `DataRow`, you
>   can add it to the `DataRowCollection`, through the `DataTable`
>   object's `Rows` property

you should add the row to your datatable like this

```
dtCustomInvoiceDetail.Rows.Add(dr);
```

also note that you can convert the whole enumerator logic to a simple for loop, it has more readability and less overhead

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(itemAmountList.Count, listItemDescriptionValues.Count); i++)
{
    var description = itemAmountList[i];
    var amount = listItemDescriptionValues[i];

    DataRow dr = dtCustomInvoiceDetail.NewRow();
    dr["itemDescription"] = description;
    dr["itemAmount"] = amount;
    dr["purchaseOrderID"] = strPoid;
}
```

also it seems that there is an inconsistency between names and variable assignments. you assign a value from `listItemDescriptionValues` to `amount` variable and from `itemAmountList` to `description`. Please double check it.

Comment: You could also use LINQ's `Enumerable.Zip` to iterate both sequences simultaneously as well.